# debian source packages for python-rospkg, python-rosdep, etc

Tags: ros, build-from-source, debian, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For most ROS .deb packages (e.g. for ros-hydro-ros), one can get the source by adding a "deb-src" line into the /etc/apt/sources.list with the same repository as the "deb" line. Then, one can download the source package files with something like:

apt-get source ros-hydro-ros

This will download the .orig.tar.gz, .dsc, and .debian.tar.gz file. So far so good. (And a great improvement from earlier versions of ROS.)

However, there are some packages for which the source cannot be downloaded this way. Where should I look for the source to packages such as python-rospkg, python-rosdep, python-vcstools, python-catkin-pkg, ps-engine and so on?

Also, I think it would be great if these were included in the same source repository as the rest of the packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187924/debian-source-packages-for-python-rospkg,-python-rosdep,-etc/) by [AndrewStraw](https://answers.ros.org/users/203/andrewstraw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2014-07-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The toolchain for building them is available at: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_release_python If you take a look at the upload logic I expect that they could be extended to push the sourcedebs as well as the binary debs to the repo.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndrewStraw](https://answers.ros.org/users/203/andrewstraw/) on 2014-07-27**:
Thanks. I've just added functionality that should make it easier to upload source https://github.com/astraw/stdeb/commit/a82fc4 . Once I make a new release of stdeb, I'll send a pull request on github.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-07-28**:
Sounds good. We'll be looking for it. It looks like you've been busy there, with the changes I see our process should get easier.

**Comment by [AndrewStraw](https://answers.ros.org/users/203/andrewstraw/) on 2014-08-10**:
Pull request sent. https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_release_python/pull/7